# Conditional rendering css/styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to create a simple dashboard page, where I have a menu at the left side of user's desktop. It should appear slowly after clicking, and gently hide while trying to get back. Everything works really fine, but I don't know how to transform this css fragment to styled-component.

Here is my code:

**Navbar.tsx**

```
function Navbar() {
    const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

    const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);

    return (
        <>
        <IconContext.Provider value={{color: '#fff'}}>
            <Nav>
                <StyledLink to="#" >
                <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar}/>
                </StyledLink>
          </Nav>
            <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>    <---- That's the line I'm trying to change
            <StyledUl onClick={showSidebar}>
                <StyledNavbarToggle>
                    <StyledLink to="#" >
                        <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />

                    </StyledLink>
                </StyledNavbarToggle>
                {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <StyledNavbarToggle key={index}>
                            <StyledLink to={item.path}>
                                <NavText />
                                {item.icon}
                                <StyledSpan>{item.title}</StyledSpan>
                            </StyledLink>
                        </StyledNavbarToggle>
                    )
                })}
            </StyledUl>
            </nav>
            </IconContext.Provider>
        </>
    )
}
```

Here is the css code for the nav-menu active and nav-menu (I'm creating components from pure css code).

**Navbar.css**

```
.nav-menu {
  background-color: #060b26;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  transition: 850ms;
}

.nav-menu.active {
  left: 0;
  transition: 350ms;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I checked this with a simple example actually that condition is correct and working properly you have to check your CSS. coz I check that with the background color so you can also check that using background color.

Comment: Can you share the output that you getting on your side?

Comment: Thanks for your help. @MayuriPapat I know that it works, but I want to change the marked line to Styled-Component, to achieve everything with the same approach. I use SC basically on each line in render(), and I'd like to change also this line, but don't know how.